# Yate Jabber Server troubleshooting - login failed not authorized error

Tags: windows

I am could install YATE 4.0 on windows xp, voice thr' SIP works fine. I wanted to enable text chat/IM as well.

I followed all the steps in this documentation, 
http://yate.null.ro/pmwiki/index.php?n=Main.BuildYateJabberServer
but when I connect using Yate Client (Qt) - it is giving me error unregistered account jabber:sham@192.168.0.1 reason : not-authorized.
more details,

1. To connect to Jabber server I am giving following details on Yate Client,
   User Name : sham
   password : mypassword
   Domain : 192.168.0.1 
   server : 192.168.0.1
   Resource : Yate
   Port : 5222
2. I kept openssl.conf 's Enable= no, I am able to create postgre SQL database and connection to the same is successful, as I checked starting Yate Console, initially it was giving error to connection string, connection string '=' missing, 
   I made to postgre SQl database, but corrections in pgsqldb.conf , there is no error on initializing module PostgreSQL.
   Did anyone tried Jabber with Yate on local server(windows) , since I want to limit the voice & IM to my local network only. this has limited or no internet.

Thanks for going thr' my query.

Regards
Sham Yemul

Answer (score 1):

I could log-in to YATE having PostgreSQL DB configured as JabberServer.

I created self signed SSL certificate for my local web server, installed same as mentioned and I kept openssl.conf 's Enable= yes

Then it worked fine. SSL certificate seems mandatory OR I could not get settings to do it without SSL certificate.